# How to select the first and last number for each letter in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

[CLICK THE IMAGE FOR THE DESCRIPTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFneV.png)

I am looking for VBA Code to for the situation above in Excel as a loop by going through the cells as in the picture above.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Requests for code which contain no code themselves, or even any description of what you've already tried, tend to get closed here.  Also, you tagged with VGA, and wrote VGA in the text...

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specifically need to use VBA, this is probably easiest with `PivotTables`, as shown in the image:

[image]